# Mostrar RSS por pantalla

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, rss

estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con RSS y la verdad es que estoy muy perdido, tengo este código pero por pantalla solo me sale "Cargando Rss..." pero nunca llega a cargar nada. ¿A que se debe esto? ¿Que hago mal?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ejemplo basico AJAX y XML</title>   
<script type="text/javascript">
function cargar(){

 var objHttp=null;
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  objHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
  objHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
 } 
  
  objHttp.open("GET", "http://www.heraldo.es/index.php/mod.portadas/mem.rss" , true);  
  
  objHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (objHttp.readyState == 4 && objHttp.status == 200) {
   console.log(objHttp.responseXML);
  var fichero = objHttp.responseXML; //recogemos el contenido 
  var noticias = fichero.documentElement;
  //var noticias = fichero.getElementsByTagName("item");
  var cadena = ""; 
  for (i = 0;i < 3; i++){    
   cadena = cadena + "Titular: " + noticias.getElementsByTagName("item")[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br/>";      
   cadena = cadena + "Descripcion: " + noticias.getElementsByTagName("item")[i].childNodes[9].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br/>";
   cadena = cadena + "enlace <a href='" + noticias.getElementsByTagName("item")[i].childNodes[7].firstChild.nodeValue + "'> Link </a><br/><br/><br/>";
   //cadena = cadena + "enlace "+ noticias.getElementsByTagName("link")[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br/><br/><br/>";
  }
  alert(cadena);
  document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = cadena;
  } 
 }
 objHttp.send(null);            
}

</script>
</head>   
 <body >   
  <div style="width:400px;height:400px; position:relative;" id="caja"> 
   Cargando Rss...
  </div> 
  <script>cargar();</script>
  </div>
 </body>   
</html>
```

¡Salud!

Comment: Hola Carlos, quieres crear un RSS o quieres leer un RSS?

Comment: @Reynald0. Yo querer quiero todo jajaja, pero si no tengo mal entendido, esto lo importa a mi web ¿no? Osea, leer

Comment: Yo he usado un JS hecho que me permite leer cualquier RSS. Te paso la web para que escojas el que mas te guste: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-rss-feed-readers/

Comment: ¿Ves algún error en la consola de JavaScript? Probando tu código recibo un error de CORS en la consola.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sí, me da error pero la verdad no se su causa, técnicamente este código tiene una finalidad didáctica pero a mi me está amargando jajaj

Comment: @CarlosMilles ¿qué error te da? Deberías compartirlo para que la gente pueda ayudarte a encontrar y solucionar la causa del problema. Dale a [edit] la pregunta para añadir esa información.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que tiene su debida complejidad leer un RSS, te puedo recomendar una librería JS.

Para leer RSS (XML) puedes usar **FeedEk** es una librería que te permitirá leer casi cualquier RSS y además elegir que cosas mostrar.

Aqui tienes un demo: https://www.jquery-plugins.net/FeedEK/FeedEk_demo.html

Prueba con la URL del RSS que quieres leer: http://www.heraldo.es/index.php/mod.portadas/mem.rss

El código que escribirías sería:

```
  $('#divRss').FeedEk({
    FeedUrl: 'http://www.heraldo.es/index.php/mod.portadas/mem.rss',
    MaxCount: 3,
    ShowDesc: true,
    ShowPubDate: false,
    DescCharacterLimit: 100
  });
```

Y tu verías en el navegador esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con un poco de calma lo puedes adaptar al estilo de tu sitio web. O simplemente mostrar los enlaces hacia la entrada (noticia o anuncio, como quieras entenderlo) del sitio que lo emite.